# Vue router: check if two routes are "siblings"

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have two route objects for which I'd like to find out whether they are "sibling routes". Two routes constitute as sibling route (according to my definition), if they have the same name and their parent parameters were the same (e.g. `/foo/1/baz/2` and `/foo/1/baz/3` would be siblings, but `/foo/2/baz/4` wouldn't be a sibling of the other two routes).

I've got most of it sorted, but can't get access to the keys of the parent route (e.g. '/foo/:bar/baz' - 'bar' in this case). I could write a parser to extract this from the path, but since this data was already extracted by the vue router, I was hoping to use that instead.

I've delved into the Vue router code (4.0.11) and found that the `matcher` (an array) which contains objects with `keys` attributes that hold the data I'm looking for (`keys` is another array of objects which - at the `name` attribute - holds the name of the parameter in the path).

Unfortunately, the router is initialised like:

```
function createRouter(options) {
  const matcher = createRouterMatcher(options.routes, options);
  ...
```

and `matcher` is not returned which keeps the `matcher` well hidden from outside use.

There's a `getRoutes()` function which I thought may return what I need, but it turns out that it doesn't return the individual matchers directly, but a `record` which doesn't contain the `keys`...

```
function createRouter(options) {
  ...
  function getRoutes() {
    return matcher.getRoutes().map(routeMatcher => routeMatcher.record);
  }
  ...
```

Is there any way I can get the parent route's parameter keys, so I can compare two (supposedly) child routes to find out whether they are siblings?

Comment: Can you show your route definition?